Why did Misty make an exception for a few bug Pokemon if she's really afraid of them?
If Misty doesn't like bug Pokemon and if she really is afraid of them, then why did she make an exception for a few of them?
For example:

Ash's Butterfree
Tracy's Scyther
Ash's Heracross

I thought she didn't like bug Pokemon at all. Does that seem like a contradiction, or is there a difference?

I wouldn't view it as a contradiction, just more of preference. While Misty does not like bug type Pokemon, she's more so afraid of bug-like Pokemon (like caterpie or weedle). She also seems to be less afraid of bug-type Pokemon if they are owned by her friends (like Heracross)

The one Pokémon type that Misty cannot stand are Bug-types, as shown in Ash Catches a Pokémon! and more recently in Alola, Alola!. The only Bug-type Pokémon Misty is not afraid of are the kinds that she deems "cute" or "pretty", like Ledyba and Butterfree, some belonging to her friends, like Tracey's Venonat, or ones that don't look like bugs, such as Pineco. However, Bug Pokémon are only one of three things Misty strongly dislikes, the other two being carrots and peppers. When asked how she feels about dual-typed Bug/Water Pokémon, such as Dewpider, Misty replied "that's a tough one".
Misty (emphasis my own)

Coming from the perspective from one who has young kids, this type of fear is not something we see only in TV shows. I see this type of behavior often when kids are grossed out by slimy caterpillars, but amazed by butterflies.

I've always found butterflies so much more unsettling than caterpillars--at least caterpillars can't fly!
